# Xcode build issue with Jenkins job

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, jenkins

I am building an iOS app and generating .app file in following two ways:

1. using Xcode in my machine
2. Jenkins job set up

In my Jenkins script, I am using the command `xcodebuild -configuration "$CONFIGS"` to generate the build. Where CONFIGS is set to one of my project  configuration. Locally, I am building a scheme which is linked to same configuration.

**Problem:** .app generated from Jenkins build crashes as soon as I launch the app on certain iOS like 8.4.1; works on certain iOS versions like 7.X. Build generated from my local Xcode works fine on all supported iOS versions.

**Diagnosis:** On further troubleshooting and build size comparison I found that size of exec file inside .app file from Jenkins is half the size of file generated from my local machine.

Anyone has idea on why there could be size difference in executable files?

Comment: Do you have anything in the crash report that could help? I'm thinking only one architecture is shipped, and that's not your device's.

Comment: There is nothing in crash report. It just crashes as soon as I launch it. I'm also thinking on similar lines. Certain architecture is missed out causing this crash. How to zero down on to the root cause.

Comment: You could check your app's binary for the architecture by using `xcrun lipo -info <yourbinaryfile>`.

Comment: I tried using 'ar' command from command line on .app but guess it works for  static library and not for .app. How do I check for possible architectures app is built of?

Comment: You can't do that on your .app file, though. You have to dive in the build result.

Comment: Could you please throw some light on this - what do you mean by dive in build result.

Comment: The .app file is actually a folder. you can navigate in it using a terminal. If what you have is an .ipa file, you'll have to unzip it.

Comment: That I understand. I was wondering how would I check the architectures my project is finally built on. Like for static library we have "file" or "ar" commands which list down all the architectures.

Comment: I got it... I just went into MyApp.app folder and ran the "file" command on MyApp exec file and it listed architectures.

Comment: Cool. Anything missing?

Comment: Yeah; this is missing -> (for architecture arm64): Mach-O 64-bit executable

Comment: How could 64 bit architecture be missing in Jenkins build?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you suspected, an architecture is missing in your app.

Check the Xcode configuration used by Jenkins, especially that the Build Settings `Build active architecture only` is on No, and that the `Valid Architecture` contains all the needed architecture (arm64 and armv7).

If you need to change something, do take care of the Debug vs. Release thing -- by default, building on your Mac usually yields a Debug build; it may not be the same on the Jenkins job.